# What's the maximum length of a BLE Manufacturer Specific Data AD?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

A BLE advertisement can send out 31 bytes at max. Inside an advertisement, there might be several ADs.

I'm wondering whether it is valid to make an advertisement contains just one Manufacturer Specific Data AD, and whether this kind of AD can fill up all the 31 bytes(1 byte of length field, 1 byte of type field(0xff), 2 bytes of CIC and 27 bytes of custom data).

Is the Bluetooth Core Specification or any other specification specify this?

Answer (score 14):

From the spec- *Supplement to the Bluetooth Core Specification
Version 4 Part A 1.4*:

> 1.4.1 Description
>
> The Manufacturer Specific data type is used for manufacturer specific
>   data. The first two data octets shall contain a company identifier
>   code from the Assigned Numbers - Company Identifiers document. The
>   interpretation of any other octets within the data shall be defined by
>   the manufacturer specified by the company identifier.
>
> 1.4.2 Format 
>                Data Type <>
>
> Description: Size: **2 or more octets** The first 2 octets contain the
>   Company Identifier Code followed by additional manufacturer specific
>   data
>
> Table 1.4: Manufacturer Specific Data Type

So there is no limit except the advertising packet length itself, which is 31 bytes per advertising data and another 31 bytes for scan response.

There is the requirement for the 3 bytes at the beginning of advertising data that have the Flags ad type (required for any non-zero length advertising, see *Core V4.0 Volume 3 Part C 11.1.3*), reducing your advertising data length by 3.

Then there is the manufacturing ad type flags and length that get added to your manufacturing data, minus another 2 bytes.  This leaves you with:

- 26 bytes in the advertising data 
  or
- 29 bytes in the scan response

for manufacturing data itself (although two of those bytes should be used for specifying the Company Identifier Code) which would bring it to:

- 24 bytes of actual data in the advertising data 
  or
- 27 bytes in the scan response.

Comment: For Core v4.0 the portion about the Flags AD is slightly incorrect. The standard allows the Flags AD to be omitted if none of the bits need to be set. But the typical advertising packet does need these flags so practically it becomes required.

For Core v5.1 (I am not exactly sure when it changed), the Flags AD usage was relaxed even more:

- Any Flag bit is set AND the advertisement packet is connectable. (From CSS v9 Part A, Section 1.3.1)

So if the advertisement is not connectable, in v5.1, you can reclaim those 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no restriction in the BT spec about the AD Type data in the avertising data (AdvData)  The AdvData can be empty or contain one/more AD Type data.  That's up to the device/app.  So there is nothing preventing you from using the full capacity for a Manufacturer Specific data.

note: AD Type formats are defined in the Core Specification Supplement.