# iOS Swift explore basic heart rate data as broadcast messages without pairing

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, heartrate

i was implementing an iOS demo app to read data from HR monitor like Polar , Wahoo. I discovered and connect/pair(ed) the devices and got data successfully from multiple simultaneous bluetooth connection.

Now my requirement is to collect data from more BLE devices(20+ in number). I tried with swift BLE API , it is not providing heart rate data without/before pairing. Besides Bluetooth does not(seems) work with this number of simultaneous connection. Someone advised me to do this like :

> "If you are interested only in basic heart rate data, that is to say beats per minute value
> then I assume that you might be able to handle 40 units as you would not have to
> actually connect with the units. It would be enough to listen to the broadcast messages
> as the broadcast messages include the beats per minute value for each device."

This means i can get basic heart rate data from broadcast messages without pairing devices. My queries :

Q1: Can i really get basic heart rate data without pairing (by discovering only) ?

Q2: Does native BLE API supports this ?

Q3: Any way/API/SDK/example to accomplish this purpose ?

Q4: It would be better if i get data in every seconds.

Q5: Can i get any help from HealthKit for this ?

**----------------Update 1 ----------------**

When i discovered BLE devices using

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) { }
```

I have found kCBAdvDataManufacturerData array with 6 value.

I followed this link to extract HR data from kCBAdvDataManufacturerData key of Polar H10 device ,  [Extract data from kCBAdvDataManufacturerData on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140636/extract-data-from-kcbadvdatamanufacturerdata-on-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But i failed, how to achieve this ?

**----------------Update 2 ----------------**

Finally got the solution , please follow this link if anyone require.

https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/issues/103

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The broadcast message your friend is referring to is the advertisement data, which is quite limited ([31 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535404/whats-the-maximum-length-of-a-ble-manufacturer-specific-data-ad)), also it depends on if you have control of the firmware in your bluetooth device.

A1: It is possible, if hardware provides that information in the advertisement data

A2: Yes, you can get advertisement data through CBCentralManager's [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518937-centralmanager)

A3: If you have implemented BLE to connect to one device, you probably already know how to use CBCentralManager, but if you need a link, here is a [CoreBluetooth tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/231-core-bluetooth-tutorial-for-ios-heart-rate-monitor)

A4: I don't think you can control the frequency of when you discover a certain peripheral

A5: I've never used HealthKit, so I cannot answer this

Comment: Thanks . nice answer. For Q4. Does not it provide data in every seconds normally ? i see this in every seconds. <CBPeripheral: 0x28301caa0, identifier = 99A3434-2E5E-5F37-7110-F9726BF3451E, name = Polar H10 E7BQ91A, state = disconnected>

Comment: Do you mean to catch key value here in advertisementData ? func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                      advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)

Comment: Yes, normally you might see data every seconds, but you don't have control to the frequency of the update.
Yes, a bluetooth device gets to decide what data it wants to advertise, you can get that without connecting to a device. Usually it is for broadcasting supported (short) service UUUID or device name. Keep in mind it is only 31 bytes, you cannot put a lot in there.

Comment: so, what value i should request from manufacturer(wahoo,polar) for data without connection ? where to set this data ? let heartRateServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x180D")
let heartRateMeasurementCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "2A37")
let bodySensorLocationCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "2A38") which one ?

Comment: Maybe take a look at `kCBAdvDataManufacturerData`, here is a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140636/extract-data-from-kcbadvdatamanufacturerdata-on-swift)

Comment: Thanks. I am getting manufacturerData.count == 6 here. So, last one is not accessible for Polar H10 devices. Any clue to get HR value from here ?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear. What I was trying to say was, it is only possible if the device provide those information.

If you are very certain that information is present, then you can try analyzing `kCBAdvDataManufacturerData`. It is a binary data (count 6 = 6 bytes), just print out value of each byte, and monitor for awhile, maybe you'll be able to figure out what these 6 bytes represent

Comment: I think Wahoo TICKR does not provide it, Polar provide it in a private way. Not extractable from using native BLE approach as i am trying, i believe they provide it and process it their own way. Polar documentation is not well organised. But i think i can get it soon. I will share if find anything. thanks

Comment: Found. manufacturerData[5],  last part is the HR data!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out~ Good job

Comment: Just another discussion. Could you please guess, what technology they used to perform session with many tickr ? BLE or ANT+ ? ANT+ does not directly supported by iOS and BLE can not connect more than 10/15 HR TICKR(sensor) concurrently. Can you guess the trick how they support 40 user ? https://apps.apple.com/us/developer/selfloops/id911739721

Comment: I have implemented this, but there is a scenario. As I am not connecting/pairing through BLE, so it can advertise any devices. Suppose, you don't touch Polar devices, but it is near to iPad(it was touched 5 minutes ago, sometimes not even touched for a long time), but it shows/emits/advertises a fixed amount of HR data automatically. I believe it is happening for the signal power of Polar, but do you know any trick to avoid devices that are not really touched?